# UIWebView: decidePolicyForNavigationAction?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm using a UIWebView in my app, and everything works fine in iOS5 and 6.
But on iOS7 the UIWebView can't load the page requested (an html from internet) and start an infinite loop with this error every 10 secs:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

The webview loadrequest is located in viewDidAppear.

I found no documentation for this *bug* for iOS.
The method **decidePolicyForNavigationAction** seems to be used only in WebKit for MacOS.. and not for iOS.

Same problem both on device and on simulator.
I saw similar topics on stackoverflow, but noone report a working solution :/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: I think you are use the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate of webview and problem in Url , please post your code

Comment: Do you still have the issue? Or how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to download new xCode version 5.0.1
This issue is fixed in version 5.0.1
Also, clean all the builds from the `path ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/~`
Build after clean. Everything works fine.
Let me know if the issue still persist.

Comment: I am using Xcode 5.1.1, but also had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

My problem was related to a library linked in the project: pspdfkit v2.x on iOS7.

Initializing the uiwebview before pspdfkit (even without presenting it) solved my problem.