# PSPDFKit and UIWebView doesn't work together

Tags: ios, uiwebview, pspdfkit

I use PSPDFKit into a static framework linked to a main project which uses another static framework with a UIWebView.

After the loading of the main project, when I launch the UIWebView and call the request, I have this error:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

and nothing appends in the webview.

If I doesn't load PSPDFKit into my first framework, the issue doesn't appear and all is ok.

I also found that if I link all the frameworks needed by PSPDFKit but not the PSPDFKit, I have the same bug. I must remove the MessageUI framework to have the right behaviour.
But when I include PSPDFKit even without MessageUI, the bug occurs.

Someone have an idea to solve it or find a workaround?

The bug occurs on iOS 7 versions, only on devices not on simulator. And all works fine in iOS 6.

I found this post [UIWebView: decidePolicyForNavigationAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497539/uiwebview-decidepolicyfornavigationaction) but the resolution is not very clear!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solve this bug. I don't know why this bug appeared and I don't know why my fix work.

In fact, I remove old code for the compatibility with iOS 5. This code used the *objc/runtime.h* library and its goal was to inject into all our UIViewController subclasses if they don't implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

We used this code to do that

```
Method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:));
class_addMethod(class, @selector(shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:), method_getImplementation(shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation), method_getTypeEncoding(shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation));
```